# Azure Waiting Statistics - PostgreSQL database performance degradation

Tags: postgresql

After moving to a new version of our platform we experienced significantly increased waiting statistics resulting in: **could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**

The following top 3 waiting statistics appear in diminishing order:

- ClientRead (1)
- IO: DataFileRead (2)
- LWLock: buffer_io (3)

We are using PostgreSQL v11 and have tables which are heavily used in small time intervals.

Before our migration we did not use websockets.

If there are any good hints where to search for solutions those would be most welcome. We have seen several resources on Azure but not specifically how to further digest these waiting statistics in a procedural manner.

Comment: Top 3 doesn't really tell us anything.  Are they 35%, 33%,, and 32%?  99.97%, 0.02%, 0.01%?

Comment: The server is complaining the client just hung up on it without saying goodbye.  What, if anything, does the client complain about?